# Can eclipse simulate user input?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I want to write a program that accepts user input. So far im good. But the amount of user input gets out of hand and is impractical to do by hand while debugging. Is there a possibility to let eclipse do the user input for me? And if yes how does it look like? The user input is a bunch of Integers that are separated in different ways. Is there a way to keep the use of the scanner, as I want to test the scanner, too?

Comment: You can always hard-code these values directly in the code.

Comment: You can make use of command line arguments if acceptable.

Comment: Eclipse is just an IDE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emulating user input for java.util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170854/emulating-user-input-for-java-util-scanner)

Comment: If you are on mac or linux you can pipe input a program java Abc < input.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `main` method has a String array passed in as an argument and this array can be "supplied" to the application when it is run.

And yes, you can do this in Eclipse in run configurations:
[image]

In the image above the we pass the arguments "10" "103" and "54" to the program.

**Example sample excerpt:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    // Assuming we passed in the previously mentioned 3 arguments.
    System.out.println(args[0]); // 10
    System.out.println(args[1]); // 103
    System.out.println(args[2]); // 54

}
```

Do note however that these are in fact `String` objects, so if you need integers be sure to convert them with calls like this:

```
int myInteger = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // Will try to parse args[0] as int.
```

Unfortunately it seems like you'll have to abandon `Scanner` with this approach but it shouldn't be overly difficult to implement this approach.

Alternatively you could comment the `Scanner` block of the code out to temporarily substitute it with this approach for testing, then once you verify the correctness of your algorithm you can switch back to the `Scanner` approach to revert to manual input for presentation or non-eclipse situations.

**EDIT :**

As proposed by [@Paco Abato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2595658/paco-abato) a nice solution to include the `Scanner` is to branch out the input processing based on whether or not any arguments were passed in upon launch.

**Example sample excerpt:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    if(args.length > 0) {
        // Process the args[] array.
    } else {
        // Process input with Scanner
    }

}
```

Comment: With this approach if there are any arguments ignore the scanner and use supplied values, elsewhere use the scanner.

Comment: @PacoAbato Added your proposition to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. As I clarified above the scanning itself should be tested too.

Comment: For the scanner part, I'll work into the answers of the question this is a possible duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a second programm that generates "user input" and sends it to the main program via localhost?